# Python - get last item in a list, using a file

Tags: python, list, file

I have a file:

[image]

I split the lines so I get this:

[image]

But I'm only  interested in the last item in each of those lists, so 77, 77, 6 etc. Is there a way to obtain them?

Comment: Suppose you call you list of lists `l`. Then, `[ x[-1] for x in l ]` will get you a list of only the last items.

Comment: @Alec why give an answer as a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you already have that array,

```
lastItems = [int(i[-1]) for i in yourList[2:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For each item, take its [-1] element. Index [-1] refers to the last element of an array, [-2] to the next-to-last, etc.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with big file:

```
>>> with open('yourfile') as f:
...     last_items = [ int(x.strip().split()[-1]) for i,x in enumerate(f) if i> 1 ]
...
```